# Как правильно пользоваться генераторами?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал генератор простых чисел:

```
def primes():
    prime = True
    i = 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime = False
        if prime:
            yield i
        else:
            prime = True
```

Но что-то я не пойму как им пользоваться. Я делаю как вызов:

```
x = primes()
print(x)
```

Выводится объект, а не число.

В случае такого вызова `print(next(primes()))` все время на выходе получаю 2.

Как правильно **пользоваться** генераторами ?

Comment: related: [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def primes():
    prime = True
    i = 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime = False
        if prime:
            yield i
        else:
            prime = True
```

Вывести все простые числа не больше 100
http://ideone.com/wiVXOE

```
for p in primes():
    if p > 100:
        break
    print(p)
```

Вывести первые 7 простых чисел:
http://ideone.com/sYrLpA

```
p = primes()

for i in range(7):
    print(next(p))
```

Comment: А кроме `for` есть способы ?

Comment: @faoxis, сорри, я питон совсем не знаю. Полагаю, что любые функйии, лениво работающие с итераторами, подойдут. Но ответ немного дополнил.

Comment: @faoxis у вас при вызове получается генератор, напр. ```a = primes()```. Чтобы получить теперь следующее значение вызовите a.next() несколько раз. Вообще почитайте про генераторы. А вообще ответ верный

Comment: @faoxis, типичный способ использования итератора - пройтись по нему с помощью `for` или передать в функцию. `next` в повседневной практике применяется достаточно редко.

Answer (score 5):

print(next(primes())) не работает так, как вы хотите, потому что при каждом вызове primes() будет возвращать новый объект-генератор, и для каждого из них next будет срабатывать один раз, и брать только первое значение.

Вам нужно сначала зафиксировать один объект-генератор в переменной, а уже потом делать для него next.

```
p = primes()
print(next(p))   # Выведет 2
print(next(p))   # Выведет 3
print(next(p))   # Выведет 5
```